# Enable DNS in Android Recovery mode

Tags: android

Trying to download one file using URL through curl library API. But always getting the

> Couldn't resolve the host name

. I'm able to get the IP address in recovery mode and able to ping the other IP addresses.

After lot of google search came to know that DNS might not be started. Something we need to make changes in init.rc file. Please let me know how to enable DNS in recovery mode.

Figured out the exact problem...
if address provided as http://www.google.com getting couln't resolve host name. If am running a local server and provided url provided as http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/ its working fine.

why the host name is not getting resolved in recovery mode?